# Changed the database connection strings to a newer version, the web app runs locally just fine, but the url returns 404 at a login page

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, amazon-web-services

The web app has Java on the back end and React on the front-end. I created a replica of a production database RDS instance in AWS that I wanted to use as the new Test database. I changed the connection strings in the .pom file and made sure everything else matches.

This was a success as I have full functionality locally. However, the url returns a 404 error at a login page. I can't log in with any of the credentials. It will tell me that the email or the username doesn't exist.

Console error:

```
api.js:66 POST http://qapage.webpage.com/api/login net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

The api.js file line 66:

```
export function postPublicResource(uri, jsonQuery) {
  var url = getUrl(uri);
  POST_PARAMETERS.body = serialize(jsonQuery);
  return fetch(url, POST_PARAMETERS)
    .then(status)
    .then(json);
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's a code issue if it runs locally?

I checked the postgres version, drivers, the urls, the database connectivity, restarted the EC2 api/ui instances. Everything works locally fine, but I can't log in on the url. What could be the issue and how do I troubleshoot something like this ?

Comment: I get a 404 for http://qapage.webpage.com/api/login in my browser .. Do you have a shell on the EC2 instance - i.e. can you get to where it's running and do `curl -v -o - http://localhost/api/login` (may need to add a Server header)??

Comment: Are you using cloud front?